# Array to json is displaying as "Array Array" in php

Tags: php

```
$json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Done");
$json .=array("mailid" => $row["mailid"], "usertype" => $row["user_type"]);


echo json_encode($json,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

*But i am getting "Array Array" as output.*

Comment: use array_merge   Combined array no dot

Comment: You cant add more items to an array using string concatenation operation **.=**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use string concatenation(.) operation  for array, user array_merge instead

Please try like this

```
$json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Done");
$json_full= array_merge($json,array("mailid" => $row["mailid"], "usertype" => $row["user_type"]));

echo json_encode($json_full,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: Yw, Very pleasure to hear that. Please mark it as correct answer :)